# Редактирование в div contenteditable

Tags: html

Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу сделать элемент `<span></span>` заблокированным для редактирования. Редактировать нужно только информацию в `<div></div>` и что бы курсор был помещен за `<span></span>`.

```css
#text {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

#text span {
  background: red;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="text" contenteditable="true">
  <span>Текст</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Как вариант, добавьте к span contenteditable="false" и будет вам счастье)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно `span` присвоить атрибут `contenteditable="false"`, и в таком случае его нельзя будет редактировать, однако так как он находиться внутри `<div contenteditable="true">` - его можно удалить из вне. Это никак не изменить.

```css
#text {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

#text span {
  background: red;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="text" contenteditable="true">
  <span contenteditable="false">Текст</span>
  &nbsp;
</div>
```

Comment: Могу ли я курсор поместить за span?

Comment: можно, добавил в код

Comment: немного не то, т.к. пробел можно удалить и опять попасть в span

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин если вам помог ответ - можете отметить его галочкой слева, успехов!